# confused about WindowsAuthenticationOptions.IdpReplyUrl

Tags: identityserver3

I'm trying to use https://github.com/IdentityServer/WindowsAuthentication

I'm confused about WindowsAuthenticationOptions.IdpReplyUrl

What kind of resource it should be pointing to?

In your examples it is pointing to "https://localhost:44333/core/was" but I don't see how this endpoint is configured.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that "was" ending does not matter and there is nothing listening to this specific ending.
WsFed middleware is just listening on all requests.
From FORM post content it is figuring out if this request should be processed.

My particular problem was solved by commenting out CallbackPath.

Answer (score 0):

The localhost/core/ URL refers to a running IdentityServer3 instance at "https://localhost:44333/core/" with "was" as a configured external identity provider (`AuthenticationType` field).

You can find a more complete example in the [IdentityServer3 samples repository](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3.Samples/blob/master/source/WebHost%20(Windows%20Auth)/WebHost/Startup.cs). In that example the AuthenticationType is called [windows](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3.Samples/blob/master/source/WebHost%20(Windows%20Auth)/WebHost/Startup.cs#L45) instead of "was", but the idea is the same.

To see the complete picture, look at their [All in one example](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3.Samples/tree/master/source/WebHost%20(Windows%20Auth%20All-in-One)).